# Align a picture in a header using css

Tags: html, css, head, html-heading

I want to move a Picture in my websites header. It Should end up being in a line with the login and registration button (similiar to the stack overflow in the header - everything in line). I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, unfortunately nothing worked.

**Header in html**

```
<img src="/static/logo.png" alt="Start" class="header_logo" id="header_logo">

{% if session['loggedin'] %}

    <button  type="button" onclick="{{ url_for('logout') }}" class="header_logout">Logout</button>

{% else %}

    <button type="button" onclick="{{ url_for('login') }}" class="header_login">Einloggen</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="{{ url_for('register') }}"
    class="header_register">Registrieren</button>

{% endif %}
```

**the css file**

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 2vw;

}

.header_login {
    background: lightcoral;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 23px;
}

.header_register {
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 23px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.header_logo{
    width: 10%;
    display: block;
    left: 0;

}
```

[Here is how it is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmA9w.png)

I'd be happy if someone could help me. :)

Comment: switch the `.header_logo { display: block; }` to `.header_logo { display: inline-block; }`. Alternativly you can do it with flexboxes or css-grid.

Answer (score 1):

What about flex? Flexboxes are more reliable than floats.

```css
.header {
  padding:1rem 0.2rem;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 2vw;

}
.header .logo img {
  width:10rem;
}
.header .logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}
.header .interaction_buttons {
   display:flex;
}
.header .interaction_buttons button:first-child {
  margin-right:1rem;
}

.header_login {
    background: lightcoral;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 23px;
}

.header_register {
    background: lightblue;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 23px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.header_logo{
    width: 10%;
    display: block;
    left: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
     <img src="https://bankingthefuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/dummylogo.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="interaction_buttons">
     <button type="button" onclick="{{ url_for('login') }}" class="header_login">Einloggen</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="{{ url_for('register') }}"   class="header_register">Registrieren</button>
  </div>
</div
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using "float" in the css?
I'm thinking that you could use the "float:right;" on the login/logout buttons.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Your anwser is a mere comment not an anwser. Dont use the anwser option unless you can with 100% certainty answer it and proof it with a code snippet and eplain what you do. However you also miss to anwser the question as the buttons are already aligned to the right just not at the same line as the logo. Last but not least, your recommendation is terrible. Using `float`for styling purpose is not only outdated but not an intended use of float. Float should only be used for floating images within a text paragraph.

Answer (score -1):

in class `.header_logo` you specified `display` property with `block` value!
`display: block;` takes the hole line, this is why your buttons are placed in the next line.

on the other hand it is better to use `float` for img and buttons

you can see some examples for `display` property here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: dont use float for such task. Float in this case is not only outdated but also a mis-used tool for it. Thats what you have flexboxes for. Float should only be used to float images within a text paragraph.

Comment: I do not disagree! the main idea of my comment was for `display` usage! I only mentioned `float` in case that he/she wanted to use some extra things for it!